# What is the compiler and runtime behaviour of throwing an exception inside a noexcept function in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, noexcept

What is the compiler and runtime behaviour of throwing an exception inside a function which is declared `noexcept`?

According to a quick experiment with some code, the gcc compiler produces the following warning message when a `throw` statement is included inside of a function which is declared `noexcept`:

```
warning `throw` will always call `terminate` [-Wterminate]
```

This is not what I had anticipated. I would have expected this to fail to compile.

If I understand correctly the warning indicates that my code compiled successfully however if the throw statement is ever reached, then terminate is called instead.

I would guess that the compiler substituted my `throw` statement for a terminate statement of some kind?

Can anyone provide further clarity on the issue? What is it about `noexcept` which guarantees that exceptions cannot be thrown from within a function, even if I deliberatly ignore the `noexcept` statement and throw an error myself anyway?

Comment: For a `noexcept` function, imagine your function body has been re-written (by the compiler) as: `{ try { /* function-body */ } catch ( ... ) { std::terminate() } }`  This is for the purposes for illustration only and not meant to represent the actually generated code.

Comment: _"...which guarantees that exceptions cannot be thrown..."_ `noexcept` is a promise by the function that an exception will not propagate out of the function, it says nothing about what happens inside the function.

Comment: It will terminate your program. If you call functions that can throw from such a function then you must handle all exceptions before returning from such a function. 
And I strongly advise not to use catch(...) for that! If you do that something possibly went (very) wrong and you are ignoring it.

Comment: Calling `terminate` is neither illegal nor immoral, so there is no reason for the compiler to reject the program.

Answer (score 3):

The standard actually specifies that a compiler should *not* reject the code.

From [[except.spec]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec)

> Whenever an exception is thrown and the search for a handler ([except.handle]) encounters the outermost block of a function with a non-throwing exception specification, the function std​::​terminate is invoked ([except.terminate]).
> [Note 1: **An implementation is not permitted to reject an expression merely because, when executed, it throws or might throw an exception from a function with a non-throwing exception specification.** — end note]

Comment: IMHO, the question of whether any particular implementation accepts any particular program should *always* be a Quality-of-Implementation issue.  There are some purposes for which an implementation that e.g. rejects any program for which stack usage cannot be statically verified may be more useful than one which would sometimes accept programs that would blow the stack in response to some inputs.  Specifying that implementations should accept programs that contain functions that could never execute meaningfully but might be executed anyway would forbid implementations from behaving...

Comment: ...in what would otherwise a more useful fashion for some kinds of customer task. While there are some tasks for which it would be more useful to accept such programs than reject them, treating the question of whether to accept or reject such programs as a Quality of Implementation issue would allow both needs to be satisfied by some implementations.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ functions *could throw exception* or *couldn't throw exceptions*. If a function is declared with an empty [noexcept-specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#1), it's a non-throwing function, and if we throw an exception from a non-throwing function. We will catch up by `std::terminate`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

Answer (score 2):

This is an excerpt from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec that should clear things up:

> Non-throwing functions are permitted to call potentially-throwing
> functions. Whenever an exception is thrown and the search for a
> handler encounters the outermost block of a non-throwing function, the
> function `std::terminate` [or `std::unexpected` *(until C++17)*] is called:
>
> ```
> extern void f();  // potentially-throwing
> void g() noexcept {
>     f();      // valid, even if f throws
>     throw 42; // valid, effectively a call to std::terminate
> }
> ```

So basically when there is a `throw` in a `noexcept` function and there it is not handled, `std::terminate` is called instead.

Answer (score 1):

`noexcept` is not a guarantee for the function author, but a promise on their part. If the author fails to uphold that promise (directly or indirectly) `std::terminate` is called. Only callers of the `noexcept` function can consider it a guarantee.

It's not a hard error to `throw` because checking whether a general piece of code throws an exception is undecidable in general (and indeed equivalent to the halting problem), so compilers aren't forced to diagnose it.

In this case, GCC is operating under a simple heuristic (seeing the `throw` expression directly) and warning you about breaking the promise you made when marking the function `noexcept`.